# Matlab: get numeric values from table

Tags: matlab

I import a sheet from Excel into matlab using the command "readtable":

```
TABLE = readtable(Excel.FN, 'sheet', Excel.Sheet);
```

The table contains both, numeric values and strings. 
If I try to access the numeric values, I can't get them as double.

```
TABLE{j,i} = '0.00069807'
```

is still a cell.

```
cell2num(TABLE{j,i}) = NaN   
cell2mat(TABLE{j,i}) = 0.00069807,
```

but this is a char. So I use

```
str2num(cell2mat(TABLE{j,i}))
```

to obtain the numeric value. There must be a simpler way. Could you please tell me the command.

Comment: Have you tried using [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) ? You can store the numbers and text into separate variables that's quite handy. Otherwose you might want to try `str2double`, it operates on cell arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on `readtable`, the `xlsread` would be better for you. Loaded data are more "matlab-friendly" with this function.

I am not sure whether there is a simpler solution with `readtable`. I think that's just the price you need to pay for not working with the "rawer" data such as CSV or simple text files.

Comment: I use the command xlsread in most of my programs, however, I hoped that readtable would be more user friendly. I still believe that there exists a command to get the numeric value from the table. Otherwise the matlab function couldn't plot them. Maybe I have to save the Excelfile in an older format (i.e. '97). I'll try that tomorrow. Best Jonas

Comment: You can try to save it as CSV (Excel can do that, but I am not sure about the result) and use csvread or well... design your own function and call that function instead of something2anything.